# Run a local SAS database

Tags: database, database-design, sas

I am very new to SAS programming. However, there is a dataset I am interested in using that data to develop algorithms. However, I will not always be connected to the internet, and so accessing the database through the web won't be an option.

Instead, I'd like to know:

1. What is the best way to copy a very large SAS database (3 TB)?
2. Whether I can use my PC (instead of dedicated hardware) to run a local SAS server and execute SAS scripts?

Comment: Alternatively, if 2 is not feasible, is it possible/recommended to convert SAS data files to a different format, like mysql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You certainly can run SAS locally, though a desktop license is expensive (depending on what products you license, perhaps $2000 for the first year).  You also certainly could store the file in MYSQL format (or anything else); MYSQL could read a comma delimited file (CSV) easily, and you can generate a create table script from SAS pretty quickly.

I would note that you don't usually reference SAS files as 'databases', though there's nothing exactly inaccurate about it; however, they are closer to 'tables' than entire databases (which usually are one self-contained unit for data and metadata for many tables).  SAS files are usually referred to as 'datasets', and collections of SAS datasets and metadata (formats catalogs, etc.) are called 'libraries'.

Copying a 3TB SAS dataset, if it's a single dataset, can be accomplished through normal file transfer methods (FTP, HTTP, windows or UNIX copy, etc.)  SAS datasets normally compress very well (ie, a 3TB uncompressed SAS dataset might easily compress to as little as 2-3GB depending on the exact details).   You may need to obtain a SAS formats catalog along with the dataset (that stores the value labels); additionally, that is OS and bitness-specific (so Windows 32-bit cannot use Unix or even Windows 64-bit formats catalogs); there are methods for obtaining the formats catalog in the appropriate version (or more commonly, obtaining a dataset dump of a catalog to recreate locally).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can licence SAS for a PC.

Are you proposing to download the 3tb data set to your local environment? Wow. If you are new to SAS and want to develop algorithms, why not start on some smaller data sets, for example those that ship with SAS itself or some you create yourself? Then once you've nailed a good algorithm, maybe the challenge of running it against a 3tb data set will be warranted.

Or maybe get a subset of the full data set first.